# How to add extra rehearsal marks in orch. score in Lilypond

Tags: notation, sheet-music, orchestra

In Lilypond (ver. 2.18.2), how can I place rehearsal marks above each staff group in an orchestral score?  Currently, it only places rehearsal marks above the top-most staff only.

Refer to the below image:  Lilypond puts the rehearsal mark highlighted in yellow; what I would like is the same rehearsal mark ("G") where the red circles are.

[image]

P.S. Anyone want to guess what work this is? :-)

Comment: Looks like Tchaik 4 to me! :-)

Comment: Aren't you supposed to add the marks manually above each system where you want one?

Comment: @KilianFoth: I like that idea, but then when I print out individual parts (other than the top-most staff's instrument's) then two symbols will appear - the rehearsal mark *and* the extra markup letter.  Not to mention I'd have to do some horizontal adjustment to get the markup aligned with the bar line.

Comment: @Richard: Was this really *that* easy to recognize? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this? Obviously some spacing tweaks are in order.

```
marks = {
 \repeat unfold 16 { s4 }
 \mark \default
 \repeat unfold 16 { s4 }
 \mark \default
}
music = {
 \repeat unfold 32 { s4 }
}
\score {
 <<  
  \new StaffGroup {
   \new Staff \music
  }
  \new Dynamics \marks
  \new StaffGroup <<
   \new Staff \music
   \new Staff \music
  >>
  \new Dynamics \marks
  \new StaffGroup {
   \new Staff \music
  }
 >>
 \layout {
  \context {
   \Dynamics
    \consists Mark_engraver
  }
 }
}
```

[image: Not incredibly elegant, but it is a start.]

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I'm a little apprehensive about conflating *rehearsal* marks with *dynamic* marks.  How will this affect existing dynamics markings in the score?  (Notice the "*p*"s in my score image.)  On a more positive note, I'm okay with the vertical spacing as I would even consider placing the rehearsal marks *below* the bottom-most staff in a group as I've seen in many scores (including the source score to this piece).

Comment: @pr1268 - Understandable. The music I typeset often does not require fine-grained detail or control, and so this usually suits its purpose. To answer your question, it will not affect existing dynamic markings in the score unless those dynamic markings are part of a Dynamics context, and you change some property inside of a Dynamics context that would affect them. For instance, overriding `RehearsalMark.color` inside of the Dynamics context will not affect any dynamics inside the Dynamics context, but `VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-relatedstaff-spacing` would.

Comment: @pr1268 - Also, see here --- http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/defining-new-contexts --- I believe this can be used to create an entirely new context that can be used for rehearsal marks alone without conflicting with any other contexts. I merely used Dynamics earlier because it seems to be a pretty bare-bones context that doesn't require a lot of tweaking.

Comment: How do I remove all the extra stacked rehearsal marks with hidden staves?  My score is "Frenched scored", i.e. with `\context { \Staff \removeEmptyStaves }` in the layout block, but the rehearsal marks are still appearing - duplicated, on top of one another.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @pr1268 - I see what you mean. I'll be honest, I'm still working it out, myself. Feels like it should be so close, but there's probably something fundamental I'm missing. If you are interested in more digging, it looks like this may provide some clues: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/internals/mark_005fengraver , although I will be of little help in explaining just what that all means.